# Merging duplicate cells into a new column with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have this problem for the class and to be completely honest I am not even sure where to start with it. (This is day 3 of learning vba in class )

This [excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yB3fq.png) is organized by the tickers in column A, and it goes on for 22,771 rows. I need to essentially combine the information in rows that have duplicate tickers to become one row per ticker, like this [solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHna1.png) they gave us.

I have been searching on google how to "merge cells", but it does not seem like that is the route I need to take here, considering I am not merging cells in the same column, but rather am combining rows with the same ticker into a brand new column on the right. The only instructions were to "create a script that loops through all the stocks for one year and outputs the information".

I do not want the answer to this as I personally learn better when I work through it myself, but if someone could at least point me in the right direction as to where to get started that would be helpful.

I have not tried anything yet, as I stated previously, I am struggling with where to even begin.

Comment: That's not what merging cells is. Look into getting unique values from a list instead

Comment: Define a range that covers the list. Sort the list by ticker and date. Create a 2 dimensions array with the first dimension going from 1 to 4 (as 4 are the results needed). Consider each cell in the ticker column: every time you find a new (different) value, increase the second dimension of the array; in the newly created "row" report the ticker name, the open value of the first day and progressively add the vol for each line of the ticker in the list; once you reach the last occurence of the ticker (i'm assuming a single year of data), get the close value and use it to determine the [...]

Comment: [...] yearly and percentage change.

Comment: Define a range that covers the list. Create a 2 dimensions array with the first dimension going from 1 to 4 (as 4 are the results needed). Consider each cell in the ticker column: every time you find a new (different) value, increase the second dimension of the array; use a series of worksheet functions to fill in the newly created "row", like SUMIF to determine the total stock volume for the given ticker.

Comment: Why the Access tag?

Comment: For a start, figure out code that loops rows to end, then figure out logic for determining when ticker and year change (will data be multi-year - your output does not show this) and grab the first Open and Last Close to calc change and percent. Can use array but not required. Another approach is to open a recordset and loop recordset. In either case, write results to cells. When you have some code with issue, post question. Data should be provided as formatted text table and/or DDL.

Answer (score 0):

Process is complicated by requirement to pull first Open and last Close for each ticket and calculate change and percentage and also calculate total vol at same time. Here is approach that uses loop of recordset. Assumes dataset is for only 1 year and rows are already ordered by ticket and date. Those angle brackets in field headers are a nuisance so I did not use them. Suggest you remove them.

```
Sub AggData()
Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim strT As String, dblOpen As Double, dblClose As Double, lngTot As Long, x As Integer, r As Integer, booEnd As Boolean

cn.Open "Provider=MSDASQL.1;DSN=Excel Files;DBQ=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";HDR=Yes';"
rs.Open "SELECT * FROM [Sheet2$]", cn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
strT = rs!Ticker
x = 1
r = 2
Do While Not rs.EOF
    If strT = rs!Ticker Then
        If x = 1 Then dblOpen = rs!Open Else dblClose = rs!Close
        lngTot = lngTot + rs!Vol
        x = x + 1
        rs.MoveNext
        If rs.EOF Then booEnd = True
    Else
        booEnd = True
    End If
    If booEnd Then
        Debug.Print strT & "," & dblOpen & "," & dblClose & "," & lngTot
        Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, 9).Value = strT
        Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, 10).Value = dblClose - dblOpen
        Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, 11).Value = Round((dblClose - dblOpen) / dblOpen, 2)
        Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, 12).Value = lngTot
        r = r + 1
        booEnd = False
        If Not rs.EOF Then strT = rs!Ticker
        lngTot = 0
        x = 1
    End If
Loop
End Sub
```